# Are there a single noun word or an idiomatic expression to describe “a curious little boy who is eager for knowledge about everything in the world”？

Tags: word-request

I am looking for some precise English words or expressions to describe a curious little boy who wants to know anything interesting in the world.

The more the better，thank you.

Maybe what I want is a single noun word or an idiomatic expression. Like "Jack-of-all-trades"...

(The only expression I know is "a curious little boy".)

Comment: What do you find unsatisfying about the phrase _curious little boy_? It sounds fine to me.

Comment: I do want more. Maybe some expressions more vivid, novel or eye-catching:)

Comment: Use a thesaurus, then, to find synonyms for _curious._

Comment: Sorry I didn't make my request clear. I need a single noun word or an idiomatic expression.

Comment: What about *pantomath*, at may not only for the "little boy" but I think you can use that. Or you can call them *inquiring boy*.

Comment: I've downvoted the question because it's one for which there is no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a catch-all expression in English to describe a boy such as the one laid out in your question.

I realise that it's not idiomatic, but "an *inquisitive* boy" is the expression that comes to mind for me when trying to describe a child's curiosity in a positive way.